# Why i modify typora's text justification is invalid?

Tags: css, macos, text-align

I modify the typora's github.css on macos in this way.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMT2v.png)

but it doesn't work，it's also align left
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LluRu.png)

Answer (score 0):

As shown in this link [[BUG]Modifying the CSS file cannot make the text justify on macbook.](https://github.com/typora/typora-issues/issues/4823), the rendering engine of Typora does not support `text-align: justify;`.